# how to change required to disable by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing to change 2nd select tag name by javascript.

**this is my HTML**

**1st select**

```
<select name="bank" id="bank" class="select" onchange="myFunction(event)">
    <option value="Bank Account" a="required">Bank Account</option>
    <option value="UPI" a="hidden">UPI</option>
</select>
```

**2nd Select**

```
<select name="bank1" class="select" id="bank1" required>
    <option disabled selected>Choose Bank Name</option>
    <option value="SBI">SBI</option>
    <option value="PNB" >PNB</option>
</select>
```

**this is my javascript**

```
function myFunction(e) {
    document.getElementById("bank1").name = e.target.a
```

but i want to change in 2nd select required to hidden

Comment: Do you mean you want to hide the second select box after function is called? You can use CSS to hide an element with `display:none`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably you are looking for setAttribute.

```js
document.getElementById("bank1").required = false;
```

And for style mutation. As @Kokodoko had already written.

```
document.getElementById("bank1").classList.add("hidden")
```

Comment: document.getElementById("bank1").hedden = false; AND document.getElementById("bank1").hedden = true; it's perfect what i want

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to hide the second select box completely?

```
function myFunction(e) {
    document.getElementById("bank1").classList.add("hidden")
}
```

CSS

```
#bank1.hidden {
     display:none;
}
```

Comment: your solution is working only 1 time if i again and again change then don't work.

Comment: .hidden {
     display:none;
}
.hiddens {
     display:block;
}         i added 2 class for hide and show

Comment: if (e.target.value == 'Account No.'){
    document.getElementById("bank1").classList.add("hiddens")
}else{
    document.getElementById("bank1").classList.add("hidden")
}